# Exoplayer cast implementation working on July 2019 but not working this month (October 2019) without changing any code, someone knows what happened?

Tags: android, casting, chromecast, exoplayer

I have implemented exoplayer with exoplayer cast extension in july 2019 and everything worked fine in august 2019 for my clients :
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.9.6'
   implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.9.6'
}
```

But suddenly, I have tested it this month (october 2019) on my chromecast and it doesn't work anymore.
Exoplayer still play video but it doesn't detect any chromecast.
My chromecast still works with Youtube cast or Netflix cast.

My code hasn't changed since august.
Someone has experience the same thing or has a clue of what is going on ?

Comment: To my best of knowledge Google regularly updates their firmware and CAF receiver. I guess the easies way to find out is to look at release notes about chromecast/firmware.

Comment: have you tried with the most recent version of com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am using below version and CastPlayer is still working. Have you tried them?

```
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.1'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.10.1'
```